# Vertical Scroll bar in sharepoint 2013 doesn't appear

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, css, internet-explorer

In the IE9 and chrome, the vertical scroll bar works for Sharepoint 2013 admin, but when I log on with read permission user it deasapear. I have tried by adding the following style:

```
#s4-workspace {overflow-y: scroll !Important;}
```

It add a fix scroll bar, I can't go Up and Down, the weard thing is when I change to IE7 in the debug mode, it breaks some style in my page but the scroll works (even if I move : `#s4-workspace{overflow-y: scroll !Important;}`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are u using a custom master page? Custom styles?

Comment: Yes, I have new design, and masterpage but it works for SP admins,

Comment: Have you used security trimmed control in your masterpage?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint, the main viewport of the webpage is not the `html` or `body` elements. Instead, they use `div#s4-workspace`, which is meant to take up 100% of the height and width (minus the ribbon).

Try adding your overflow-y to this element:

```
#s4-workspace
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Or Else**

Check this `-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;` for IE9 higher version

refer [Sharepoint 2010 – IE9 – No Vertical Scrollbars](http://allthingsdotnet.net/804/sharepoint-2010-ie9-no-vertical-scrollbars)

Answer (score 0):

the "!Important" has to have a small "i". Don't know if that will help you in this case though. It sounds like you have done something to artifacts that SharePoint adds only when admin and therefore lacks the possibility to add a scroll to the workspace element. Do you use "float" or anything like that in the CSS ?

Comment: Isn't css case insensitive? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559205/are-css-selectors-case-sensitive

Comment: nothing changes, I use float in placeholders, I just custom the leftnav and placeholder.

Comment: CSS is case sensitive. It may have something to do with float. Try to use the clearfix tech http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html#.VBwaYby1bCM

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the master page is published. Changes to the master page only show for the user that has made changes until it is published. Even after 8 years working in SharePoint, I find myself baffled about something because I forgot to publish the master page.

Also make sure the user you are testing with has access to the css files. Sometimes css files are placed in a different site collection and the user will not have access to it.

It could also be that the layout is different for the test user because of access. Layout differences could change the way scroll shows between users.

Goodluck.